# AppDelegate doesn't access updated struct variable - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, appdelegate

I have a struct which looks like this

```
struct myStruct {
    var array1: [String]
    var additionalInfo: String?
    var array2: [String]
}

var appendMe = [myStruct(array1: ["Value1"], additionalInfo: nil, array2: ["Value1","Value2"])]
```

in **MainViewController** i append it with additional values, but when i try to access them from the **AppDelegate**, for instance like this

```
appendMe[array1.count-1].array2[0]
```

I always keep getting the original values set in the struct before the update. Just like Xcode creates a separate instance of the struct for **MainViewController** and **AppDelegate**.

How to i fix this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structs are passed by value in Swift, not by reference. Your main view controller is modifying a copy of the struct, not the one you think.

Comment: how do i access it's copy then?

Comment: Don't access a copy or try passing by reference. Wrap the struct in an object and you'll be fine.

Comment: @HermannKlecker tried wrapping it into a class with NSObject properties, but to no avail. How should i wrap it up inside an object?

Comment: Just create a new class, not nesseccarily an NSObject inheritance, a plain swift object would do. And its only property is of type MyStruct. That's basically it.